# perl - how to catch empty cell with regex

Tags: regex, perl

output:

```
id | status   | name             | cluster | ip          | mac               | roles | pending_roles   | online
---|----------|------------------|---------|-------------|-------------------|-------|-----------------|-------
11 | discover | Untitled (9a:3a) | 12      | 10.20.0.144 | c8:1f:66:ce:9a:3a |       | cinder          | True
12 | discover | Untitled (9f:8d) | 12      | 10.20.0.186 | c8:1f:66:ce:9f:8d |       | cinder, compute | True
10 | discover | Untitled (c7:f3) | None    | 10.20.0.214 | c8:1f:66:ce:c7:f3 |       |                 | True
13 | discover | Untitled (9f:3d) | None    | 10.20.0.233 | c8:1f:66:ce:9f:3d |       |                 | True
8  | discover | Untitled (74:8e) | 12      | 10.20.0.184 | c8:1f:66:ce:74:8e |       | controller      | True
14 | discover | Untitled (75:4b) | None    | 10.20.0.185 | c8:1f:66:ce:75:4b |       |                 | True
9  | discover | Untitled (76:23) | None    | 10.20.0.213 | c8:1f:66:ce:76:23 |       |                 | True
```

my regex:

```
\d+)\s+\|\s+(\w+)\s+\|\s+\w+\s+\((\S+)\)\s+\|\s+(\d+)\s+\|\s+(\S+)\s+\|\s+(\S+)\s+\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|\s+(\w+)
```

but cant catch the empty cells! I have tried many ways.

line example:

```
13 | discover | Untitled (9f:3d) | None    | 10.20.0.233 | c8:1f:66:ce:9f:3d |       |                 | True
```

Comment: When you have delimited data, it's much easier to use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) (or [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) if the fields could contain the delimiter).

Comment: link to text file http://textuploader.com/xcda

Comment: Please don't put your input data off-site. If the link breaks, future visitors to this page wouldn't be able to see the data and the question would no longer make sense.

Comment: `\S*` instead of `\S+`

Comment: Using split or Text::CSV are the most common choices but in this case, I might use unpack to extract each field.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where is your data coming from? It looks like the results of a SQL query...

Comment: @RonBergin : Congratulations on recognizing fixed-width fields.  An approach that leverages the strengths of the design decision that led to fixed width fields is more appropriate than an approach that ignores this rare luxury. ;)

Comment: @DavidO - The funny thing is that I don't use pack/unpack very often, even when I recognize that it would be the better approach. :)

Comment: @RonBergin I don't see what `unpack` offers over `split` in this case. `unpack` would make sense if there were no delimiter between fields, but `my @fields = split {\|}, $line;` is much clearer than `unpack 'A2 x3 A8 x3 A16 x3 A7 x3 A11 x3 A17 x3 A5 x3 A15 x3 A*', $line;` Also, this looks like the output from a database query; I'm guessing the column widths would change for different result sets. As ikegami points out, though, `split` fails if the data contains any pipes.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, Also, it should be faster to `unpack`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot : If it is the result of a DB query, then yes, treating it as fixed-width data is not advantageous.  If it *is* fixed-width, however, treating it as such eliminates the point you made in the last sentence (that `split` fails if the data contains pipes).  The advantages to treating fixed-width with tools such as `unpack` are avoidance of the embedded / escaped delimiter issue, and speed.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I also thought that it may be the result set of an sql query but it may be from a prior script that saved it as a text file which now needs parsing.  Using `split ' '` would not give the proper results in this case but maybe `split /\s+\|\s+/`

Comment: @RonBergin, DavidO, ikegami Looking at ikegami's answer, `unpack` is clearly the best solution. If this is output from a database query, I doubt fields containing pipes would be quoted like in a CSV. Looking at the widths of the column headers saves you from constructing an ugly template for `unpack` *and* is flexible so the column widths can change. Kudos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to treat structured data as unstructured lines.  You have pipe-delimited data, so parse it as pipe-delimited data and then examine the contents of what you've parsed.

Note that I'm using a regex (`/^\s*$/` to see if it is all whitespace) on the individual cell, but not on each line.

Here's an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my @cells = split /\|/, $line, -1;
    my $ncells = scalar @cells;
    die "There should be 9 fields, but line $. has $ncells" unless $ncells == 9;
    for my $i ( 1 .. $ncells ) {
        if ( $cells[$i-1] =~ /^\s*$/ ) {
            print "Cell #$i on line $. is empty\n";
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
id | status   | name             | cluster | ip          | mac               | roles | pending_roles   | online
---|----------|------------------|---------|-------------|-------------------|-------|-----------------|-------
11 | discover | Untitled (9a:3a) | 12      | 10.20.0.144 | c8:1f:66:ce:9a:3a |       | cinder          | True
12 | discover | Untitled (9f:8d) | 12      | 10.20.0.186 | c8:1f:66:ce:9f:8d |       | cinder, compute | True
10 | discover | Untitled (c7:f3) | None    | 10.20.0.214 | c8:1f:66:ce:c7:f3 |       |                 | True
13 | discover | Untitled (9f:3d) | None    | 10.20.0.233 | c8:1f:66:ce:9f:3d |       |                 | True
8  | discover | Untitled (74:8e) | 12      | 10.20.0.184 | c8:1f:66:ce:74:8e |       | controller      | True
14 | discover | Untitled (75:4b) | None    | 10.20.0.185 | c8:1f:66:ce:75:4b |       |                 | True
9  | discover | Untitled (76:23) | None    | 10.20.0.213 | c8:1f:66:ce:76:23 |       |                 | True
```

Comment: Thx alot @Andy Lester, your solution is by far the simplest and correct for getting those cells.

Comment: `split(/\|/, $line, -1)` is not that much simpler than `unpack('A2 x3 A8 x3 A16 ...', $line)`, and it fails if the data contains `|`.

Answer (score 4):

```
chomp( my $header = <> );
chomp( my $sep    = <> );

my $pat =
   join ' x3 ',
      map "A".(length($_)-2),
         "-$sep-" =~ /(-+)/g;

my @headers = unpack($pat, $header);
while (my $line = <>) {
   my %row; @row{@headers} = unpack($pat, $line);

   # Do whatever here.
   print("Row id=$row{id} has no pending roles\n")
      if !length($row{pending_roles});
}
```

Output:

```
Row id=10 has no pending roles
Row id=13 has no pending roles
Row id=14 has no pending roles
Row id=9 has no pending roles
```

Comment: Unlike @Andy Lester's solution, this one won't fail if the data contains a `|`.

Comment: Excellent choice: Using the header to determine the field widths so that there is no sensitivity to the possibility of field widths to differ from one call to the next (as could be the case of the data is a dump from a DB query).

Comment: I like it.  This solution also illustrates a quote I'm fond of.. 
http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Comment: My solution had two problem relating to the last field. Fixed.

Comment: Hi ikegami, thx for the solution. but it fails on the line with ----

Comment: if you want to help, help by giving a clear code and attach your notes. your expectation is that everyone understand you.. this is not why i came here. your code failed on line : my @headers = unpack($pat, $header); . if you provided notes about what you did i could debug it

Comment: `$pat` contains `A2 x3 A8 x3 A16 ...` and your columns are 2, 8, 16, ... characters wide with three characters between them. What do you find unclear?!?

Comment: If you want me to help, you'll need to provide the code you used, the data you used and the error you got. I can't help you with something I know nothing about.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a regex, just try to make it as small as possible. Also assuming you have no |'s in your data or anything..

```
my $r = 0; 
foreach my $row (@rows) { 
    my $c = 0; 
    print "Row $r\n"; 
    while($row =~ /([^|])*(\||$)/g) { 
        my $col = $1;
        print "    $c: $col\t"; 
        if ($col =~ /^\s+$/) { print "whitespace only!" }
        print "\n"; 
        $c++;
    }  
    $r++;
}
```